# Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 404: Connection to smtp.gmail.com:465 Timed Out

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My goal is to send activation link to my registered users.

---

Here is settings in my `.env` file for **SMTP**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=khdpqvwzbsvpixvx
```

Did I missed anything ? I kept getting :

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 404:
>   Connection to smtp.gmail.com:465 Timed Out

Comment: At the bottom of page https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps is a switch button for "Allow less secure apps". You must turn it on if it is disabled.

Comment: Since, I have 2 ways authentication enable. I don't really see that options when I scrolled all the way down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your .env file under root project. Edit following Lines in it :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587 #Update from 465 to 587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
```

Restart local webserver & It worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Secure SSL/TLS Settings (Recommended)** 
Outgoing Server:    mail.yourdomain.com
    SMTP Port: 465 
But
 **Non-SSL Settings (NOT Recommended)** 
Outgoing Server:    mail.yourdomain.com
    SMTP Port: 587

So use this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.yourdomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@yourdomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword
```